# Angularfire2 how to combine two list

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2, angularfire5

I am using Angularfire2 v5. In my database I have two lists one is `cart`and other one is `product`. In cart list there is a field which contains product id and now I want a `Observable` that contains data for both the cart and it's product. Currently I am trying with this way

```
cart: Observable<any>;
constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

ionViewDidLoad() {

this.cart = this.db.list(`/cart`)
  .snapshotChanges()
  .map(changes => {
    return changes.map(c => {
      let productObservables:Observable<any> = this.db
        .list(`product/${c.key}`).snapshotChanges()
        .map(m=>{
            m.map(p=>({
              key:c.payload.key, ...p.payload.val()
            }));
            return m;
        });
        return productObservables;
    })
  });
```

now in html using this

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of cart|async">
  <ion-label>
    {{item.key}}
    {{item.name}}
  </ion-label>
```

but it shows me null. How can I display both data the cart and product list in one `ngFor` async

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you had a structure like this:

```
cart:
  yyy:
    productId: aaa
    qty: 2
  zzz:
    productId: bbb
    qty: 1
products:
  aaa:
    name: AAA
  bbb:
    name: BBB
```

Then you could map it against the other part of the db, since you already have the key I'm just using `valueChanges()` here.

```
this.cart = this.db.list(`/cart`)
  .snapshotChanges()
  .map(changes => 
    changes.map(c => ({
      key: c.payload.key,
      product: this.db.object(`products/${c.payload.val().productId}`).valueChanges(),
      ...p.payload.val()
    }))
  );
```

The product will then be async, so you'd need to pipe that in your view too:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of cart | async">
  <ion-label *ngIf="item.product | async; let product; else loading">
    {{product.name}} x {{item.qty}} {{item.key}}
  </ion-label>
<ion-item>
<ng-template #loading><ion-spinner></ion-spinner></ng-template>
```